# Disable/delete select option based on another select option data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show options from #cities2 if #cities option value is matching #cities2 data-attribute value.

For example if in first select **Miami** is selected then in second select box only show **Miami** and remove or disable all other options from #cities2.

Here is my code which I am trying:

```
<select name="cities" id="cities">
    <option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
    <option value="Miami">Miami</option>
    <option value="Las Vegas">Las Vegas</option>
    <option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>
</select>

<select name="cities2" id="cities2">
    <option data-cities="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
    <option data-cities="Miami">Miami</option>
    <option data-cities="Las Vegas">Las Vegas</option>
    <option data-cities="Chicago">Chicago</option>
</select>

<script>
 $('#cities').change(function(e){
    var $option = $('#cities2 option').data('cities');
    if($(this).val() == "Miami" && $option == "Miami" ){
       $("#cities2 option").prop('disabled',true);           
       $("#cities2 option[data-cities='Miami']").prop('disabled',false);

    }else {
       $("#cities2 option").prop('disabled',false);
    };
 });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you getting any console error?

Comment: @Shahzad no, I am not getting any console error.

Comment: @TheFool Could you please give me jsfiiddle link so i can see. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cities" id="cities">
    <option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
    <option value="Miami">Miami</option>
    <option value="Las Vegas">Las Vegas</option>
    <option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>
</select>

<select name="cities2" id="cities2">
    <option data-cities="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
    <option data-cities="Miami">Miami</option>
    <option data-cities="Las Vegas">Las Vegas</option>
    <option data-cities="Chicago">Chicago</option>
</select>

<script>
  $('#cities').change(function(e){
    var option = $(this).val();
    console.log("Selected first: " + option);
    
    if ($(this).val() == "Miami" && option == "Miami") {
      console.log("This is Miami");
      $("#cities2 option").prop('disabled',true);           
      $("#cities2 option[data-cities='Miami']").prop('disabled', false);
      $("#cities2 option[data-cities='Miami']").prop('selected',true); 
    } else {
      console.log("Not Miami");
      $("#cities2 option").prop('disabled', false);
    };
  });
</script>
```

You have an error at the start of javascript. That is worked solution (not universal, as your example too)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('#cities').change(function(e){
    var $option = $('#cities2 option');
    var $selectedValue = $('#cities option:selected').val();

    $.each($option, function(inedx, option){
        var disabled = $selectedValue !== $(option).val();
      $(option).prop('disabled', disabled);
    });
 });
```

Also here is the fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/765803/)